# Getting error from window service with Exception code: 0xc0000005

Tags: c#, windows-services

We are getting error on server and our service is automatically stopped in the server.
Randomly application is crash in approx 1 hour with below Error as -

> Faulting application name: Chubb.Studio.Event.Processor.exe, version:
>   0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5c0ab1b7 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19425, time stamp: 0x5d26b6e9 Exception code:
>   0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0000000000001556 Faulting process id:
>   0x115c Faulting application start time: 0x01d5a35fd202f96d Faulting
>   application path:
>   E:\WindowsService\DevInt\Chubb.Studio.EventProcessor\Chubb.Studio.Event.Processor.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   762c15d4-0f5b-11ea-8120-005056a27597 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Our Code is look like as -

```
   protected override void OnStarted()
    {
        //IntializeEventsExecution();
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => IntializeEventsExecution());

        base.OnStarted();

    }

    public void IntializeEventsExecution()
    {
        StartEvents();

    }

    public void StartEvents()
    {
        var eventList = GetEventTopics();
        Parallel.ForEach(eventList,
           new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = eventList.Count },
           (item, state, index) =>
           {
               StartProcessingEvent(eventList[(int)index]);
           });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index"></param>
    public void StartProcessingEvent(EventTopic topic)
    {
        try
        {
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExecuteProcessingEvent(topic));
            task.Wait();                
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {

            new _processingDelegate(StartProcessingEvent).Invoke(topic);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to do some more work on your side before anyone here can help. Windows Services can be tricky to debug because you don't always get a helpful error. You're going to need to add a lot of try-catches with really good logging so you can find out exactly where any why the service is failing.

Comment: 0xC0000005 is STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION which means some code is reading or writing memory where it is not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

As Klaus says in his comment, a STATUS_ACCESS-VIOLATION exception is caused by a process reading or writing memory that it doesn't own. Given this is C#, the most likely reason is either an incorrect use of [P/Invoke](http://pinvoke.net/) or using [unsafe code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/).

The best approach to debugging something vague like this is to isolate the issue by removing P/Invoke calls one by one until the exception doesn't happen. It's hard to be more precise because the exception may be triggered a long way from the cause (memory or stack corruption).

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402957/what-are-some-techniques-for-troubleshooting-very-intermittent-access-violation-o) gives a good list of the likely causes of an access violation in managed code.

> Access violations in managed apps typically happen for one of these
>   reasons:
>
> - You P/Invoke a native API passing in a handle to a managed object and the native API uses that handle. If you get a collection and
>     compaction while the native API is running, the managed object may
>     move and the pointer becomes invalid.
> - You P/Invoke something with a buffer that is too small or smaller than the size you pass in and the API overruns a read or write
> - A pointer (IntPtr, etc) you pass to a P/Invoke call is invalid (-1 or 0) and the native isn't checking it before use
> - You P/Invoke a native call and the native code runs out of memory (usually virtual) and isn't checking for failed allocations and
>     reads/writes to an invalid address
> - You use a GCHandle that is not initialized or that somehow is pointing to an already finalized and collected object (so it's not
>     pointing to an object, it's pointing to an address where an object
>     used to be)
> - Your app uses a handle to something that got invalidated by a sleep/wake. This is more esoteric but certainly happens. For example,
>     if you're running an application off of a storage card, the entire app
>     isn't loaded into RAM. Pieces in use are demand-paged in for
>     execution. This is all well and good. Now if you power the device off,
>     the drivers all shut down. When you power back up, many devices simply
>     re-mount the storage devices. When your app needs to demand-page in
>     more program, it's no longer where it was and it dies. Similar
>     behavior can happen with databases on mounted stores. If you have an
>     open handle to the database, after a sleep/wake cycle the connection
>     handle may no longer be valid.